# How to handle request in multi-threading using task?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

Hi i have one `List<List<string>>` suppose we says it batchList now i want to first process on four batch and then other two batches how can i achieve this

Code is below:

```
List<List<string>> termsBatches = searchTerms.Split(2).ToList(); //batchList Count is 6
List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>(); //initialize task list for wait
foreach (List<string> batch in termsBatches)
{

 Task<SolrSearchResults> task = Task<SolrSearchResults>.Factory.StartNew(()=>
 {
      //Do Somethisng
 });

 taskList.Add(task);
 Task.WhenAll(taskList.ToArray());
 foreach (Task<SolrSearchResults> result in taskList)
 {
      //Process result
 }
```

}

after processing result of four request i want to fire other two request so how can i achieve this thing?

Comment: Can you explain more clear pls? I don't understand what do you want?

Comment: I will describe your task the way I understood it. Could you please confirm whether this understanding is right or wrong. >> You have a collection of 6 items to process. You want to process the first 4 items first - in async manner with 4 independent tasks. And then, after all these 4 are done, the last 2 items in 2 independent async Tasks. << Is that right? If it is, could you please update your decription?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle items as they arrive and use multithreading then you should look at using Microsoft's Reactive Framework (NuGet "System.Reactive").

Then, assuming you have a method `Task<SolrSearchResults> GetSolrSearchResults(List<string> batch)`, you can do this:

```
List<List<string>> termsBatches = new List<List<string>>()
{
    new List<string>() { "apple", "banana" },
    new List<string>() { "cat", "dog" },
};

IObservable<SolrSearchResults> query =
    from batch in termsBatches.ToObservable()
    from result in Observable.FromAsync(() => GetSolrSearchResults(batch))
    select result;

IDisposable subscription =
    query
        .Subscribe(result =>
        {
            //Process result
        });
```